# pywinAuto - working with Windows MFC controls

Tags: python, mfc, pywinauto

have anyone explored pywinAuto works handling windows MFC contorols? my custom built application primarly on .net also uses technologies like MFC and C++ and pure custom grids. Wondering anyone have handled such complex apps with pywinAuto

Comment: Windows standard controls support UI Automation. MFC has C++ wrapper for these controls, they are the same thing, as far as python is concerned. A custom grid control may not support UI Automation.

Comment: Native custom grid can be handled by creating custom wrapper and by handling custom window messages on app side. We did this on my previous job, but this work can’t be published. Is there any more details on custom grids? Maybe these grids have open source implementation?

Comment: below is the swapy spy and the properties looks like on the custom grids

Comment: 'Access names : [u'17', u'CSCtrlGrille']
Class : CSCtrlGrille
ClientRects : [<RECT L0, T0, R994, B589>]
ControlID : 68858368
ExStyle : 0
Fonts : [<LOGFONTW 'MS Shell Dlg' -11>]
FriendlyClassName : CSCtrlGrille
handle : 3017350
MenuItems : []
pwa_type : <class 'pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.HwndWrapper'>
Rectangle : (L1058, T298, R2068, B903)
Style : 1345388544
Texts : ['']
UserData : 0'

i want to handle the grid as rows and columns. traverse through all elements and find the records or click on records.

Comment: from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().Start(cmd_line=...."')
afxfa = app[.....]
afxfa.Wait('ready')
csctrlgrille = afxfa[u'17']
csctrlgrille.RightClick()

app.Kill_()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html:

The list of supported accessibility technologies on Windows:

- Win32 API (backend="win32") - a default backend for now

  - MFC, VB6, VCL, simple WinForms controls and most of the old legacy apps
- MS UI Automation (backend="uia")

  - WinForms, WPF, Store apps, Qt5, browsers

Also, check [Vasily Ryabov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3648361/vasily-ryabov)
(pywinauto developer)'s answer from this post: [Free automated Testing tools for MFC based GUI App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051115/free-automated-testing-tools-for-mfc-based-gui-app/32768865#32768865)